# Angular 4 - Redirect to external URL in guard with serverside rendering support

Tags: angular

I havn't found any solution this small problem yet. But here is the situation:

I have a guard that has to check the presence of a auth-cookie. If it is not there, the guard should redirect to a single-sign-on page else where ( not on the same subdomain ). Using `Location.go()` didn't seem to work nor does the router has any abilities to navigate to an external URL.

Here is the guard-code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { CanActivate, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { CookieService } from '../services/cookie.service';
import URL = require('url-parse');
import { Document } from '../components/document/document';

@Injectable()
export class CookieGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private cookieService: CookieService, private location: Location) { }

private getLoginRedirectUrl(currentUrl) {
        const protocol = new URL(currentUrl).protocol;
        switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
            case 'PROD':
            case 'production':
            case 'build':
                return `http://sso-portal.xxxxxxx.com`;
            case 'TEST':
            case 'testing':
                return `http://sso-portal-test.xxxxxxx.com`;
            default:
                return `http://sso-portal-dev.xxxxxxx.com`;
        }
    }

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if (!this.cookieService.checkCookie(('auth-cookie'))) {
            const redirectUrl = this.getLoginRedirectUrl(state.url);
            this.location.go(redirectUrl);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        return this.canActivate(route, state);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, maybe you could try with

```
window.location(redirectUrl);
```

Comment: window can't be used on serverside rendering

Comment: Didn't know you where using server-side rendering ... If so, then you should try to send a response such as `response.writeHead(301, { Location: 'url' }); response.send()` for NodeJS (adapt it to your server) to your guard.

Comment: ok, that helped me a little bit. I think i have to create a new service in angular with checks on the environment end then return the right code block for that environment. Thanks